# UIView not changing the width and height on Rotate

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation

my problem is here when I rotate the device from portrait to landscape my custom uiview doesn't change their width and height. So when the device is on landscape it still gets the width and the height of the device on portrait. So far this is my code:

```
import UIKit

class BasicView: UIView {

    let centerView: UIView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "orientationChanged", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("orientation or other bounds-impacting change")
    }

    func orientationChanged() {
        centerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,556.0,290.0);
    }

    func setupView() {
        centerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height)
        self.addSubview(centerView)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the frame according to conditions. Try this:

```
func orientationChanged()
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {            
        print("landscape") // set frame for landscape
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        print("Portrait") // set frame for portrait
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not even changing the height and width for your view, add below code to your `orientationChanged()` to know the device current orientation and resize it.

```
func orientationChanged() {

    // Consider using UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width and height in CGRect   
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        print("landscape")
        centerView.frame = // CGRect for landscape
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        print("Portrait")
        centerView.frame = //CGRect for portrait
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the basicView class's view not it's subview only.

```
func orientationChanged() {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,556.0,290.0);
}
```

Also, you need to check the current device orientation and set the frame according to orientation

```
func orientationChanged() {
    if(isLandscape) {}
    else {}
}
```